# jQuery unable to combine val() with parent()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the class 'ajax_fields'. The page contains multiple tables so I have to make use of the jQuery parent() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.hide_table').live('click', function() {
        alert($(this).parent(".row").find('.ajax_fields').val());
    });    

});
```

Above you see my jQuery code.

```
<div id="content">
<div id="id_pages">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table width_100">
            <input type="hidden" class="ajax_fields" value="title,url" />
            <input type="hidden" class="ajax_table" value="pages" />
            <div class="form_title">
                <h2>Pagina's</h2>
            </div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10px"></td>
                        <td width="10px"></td>
                        <td>title <a class="hide_table" id="verberg_title">x</a></td>
                        <td>url <a class="hide_table" id="verberg_url">x</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you see the relevant HTML code, when I click I get an alert saying 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?!

I have also tried the following options, but they also didn't work.

```
$(this).parent(".row").children('.ajax_fields').val();
$(this).closest('.ajax_fields').val();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `live()` anymore.

Comment: Did you try looking at the error console? If I try and use `live()` I get the message [`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VPgAa/).

Comment: @DavidThomas That's because your jQuery is too recent =p

Comment: @DavidThomas I didn't get any error message about live().

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? @Jack: I know; that was the *point* of the demonstration.

Comment: @DavidThomas I knew that you knew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('.hide_table').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click
    alert($(this).closest('.row').find('.ajax_fields').val());
});
```

- `$(this)` will give you the link you have clicked.
- `closest('.row')` will give you the first element that matches the selector `'.row'` by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.
- `find('.ajax_fields').val()` will find the `ajax_fields` input and get its value.

Answer (score 0):

use    [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) .live() is deprecated

```
    $(document).on('click','.hide_table', function() {
        alert($(this).closest('.row').find('.ajax_fields').val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` only searches the immediate parent, and `.children()` only searches the immediate child. You can use `.parents()` and `.find()` instead:

```
$(this).parents(".row").find('.ajax_fields').val();
```

Also, `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9. See [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get from `.hide_table` to `.ajax_fields` you can use `.closest()` to select the `<div class="row">` by iterating over the parents, after which you perform a `.find()`:

```
$(this)
    .closest('.row')
    .find('.ajax_fields')
    .val();
```

Also, you shouldn't use `.live()` anymore, because it's [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/). It's a good practice to use event delegation using `.on()` instead:

```
$('#id_pages').on('click', '.hide_table', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

Lastly, it's not advisable to omit the `href` attribute on anchors:

```
<a href="#" class="hide_table" id="verberg_title">x</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="hidden" class="ajax_fields" value="title,url" />` is not an ancestor of `<a class="hide_table" id="verberg_title">x</a>` and of course it isn't its parent element. It's just like a family tree, a distant cousin cannot be your father <sub>(well, not normally)</sub>.

You basically need to find a real common ancestor:

```
$(this).closest(".table") // $(this).closest(".row") will also do
```

... and then find the appropriate descendent:

```
.find('.ajax_fields')
```